# Python wont take a value from a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this assignment question and I wrote the following code for it. But Python keeps telling me that "Reservoir" is not in the dataframe even though it is. How do I fix this?
Here is a link to the .CVS file if needed. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SZ639cUA3DdrlI_lG2Hq0vs6HiT8OAU3/view?usp=sharing

1. Create and show a Bar Chart showing the number of wells by county:

- Category: County
- Y Axis: Total Clearfork Wells (Named "Reservoir" in file)

My code is below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('CF Around Lubbock Production Table.CSV')

By_County = df.groupby(['County/Parish']).sum().Reservoir

x = By_County.index
y = By_County.values

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))

plt.bar(x,y)


for i, j in zip(x,y):
    plt.text(i, j+10, int(j), ha = 'center')


plt.xlabel('County', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Total Clearfork Wells', fontsize = 20)

plt.xticks(fontsize = 12)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Copy/paste some of the csv data instead of asking to click a link.

Comment: Check that the headers are of string type. Can you `groupby.sum()` using another column header?

Comment: It's not clear where the error is occurring. You should include the error message in your post. To debug, I would print out df.head() to ensure the column names are as expected ('Reservoir' is indeed a column name).

Comment: This is the error it gives.  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Reservoir'

Comment: It's also helpful to know which line in the script threw the error. The second question is what are the column names of the df that threw the error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df_grouped=data.groupby(['County/Parish','Reservoir'])['Reservoir'].count()
```

Output:

```
County/Parish  Reservoir      
CROSBY (TX)    CLEAR FORK         1837
               CLEARFORK             2
GARZA (TX)     CLEAR FORK           22
               CLEARFORK            32
HALE (TX)      CLEAR FORK            2
               CLEARFORK           441
HOCKLEY (TX)   CLEAR FORK          485
               CLEARFORK           218
               CLEARFORK, LO         1
               L. CLEARFORK          1
               LOWER CLEARFORK      26
               UPPER CLEARFORK      13
LAMB (TX)      CLEAR FORK            3
               CLEARFORK           108
               L. CLEARFORK          1
               LOWER CLEARFORK      12
LUBBOCK (TX)   CLEAR FORK          726
               CLEARFORK           300
               CLEARFORK, LO        60
               CLEARFORK, LO.        4
               L. CLEARFORK          2
               LOWER CLEARFORK       1
               UPPER CLEARFORK       9
LYNN (TX)      CLEARFORK             1
TERRY (TX)     CLEAR FORK            3
               CLEARFORK             1
               CLEARFORK, LO         2
               CLEARFORK, LO.        2
               LOWER CLEARFORK       1
Name: Reservoir, dtype: int64
```

Below code will allow you get the count of the specific group:

```
df_grouped=data.groupby(['County/Parish','Reservoir'])
    CROSBY_TX_CLEAR_FORK_count= df_grouped.get_group(('CROSBY (TX)', 'CLEAR FORK'))['Reservoir'].count()

CROSBY_TX_CLEAR_FORK_count
```

You can change the parameters inside get_group to get the count of your wished group.

This will plot bar graph for reservoir 'CLEAR FORK' for all County/Parish types.

```
CLEAR_FORK_Count={}

count=0

for cat in data['County/Parish'].unique():
    try:
        count = df_grouped.get_group((cat, 'CLEAR FORK'))['Reservoir'].count()  
    except:
        count=0
    
    CLEAR_FORK_Count[cat]=count

plt.bar(CLEAR_FORK_Count.keys(), CLEAR_FORK_Count.values())
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
```

Solution:

```
def getUniqueReservoirs(x):
    return x.nunique()

rs=data.groupby(['County/Parish','Reservoir']).agg({'Entity ID':'count',
                                                    'Reservoir':getUniqueReservoirs
                                     })
rs
```

Plotting the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rs.plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes that is it. The plot x-labels are overlapping eachother now. How would you fix this?

Comment: The overlapping can be avoided using plt.xticks(rotation=45) or whatever degree you wish to indent it.

Comment: I got another solution while solving another dataset for myself. Editing the post with my latest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Column `Reservoir` appears to be of type `object` (values are strings in your case). So pandas won't sum columns with string values, if you aggregate on the whole dataframe, hence the column is left out.

What you can try:

```
By_County = df.groupby(['County/Parish'])['Reservoir'].sum()
```

It works on Series. But do you really want concatenated strings?

```
County/Parish
CROSBY (TX)     CLEAR FORKCLEAR FORKCLEAR FORKCLEAR FORKCLEAR ...
GARZA (TX)      CLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKC...
HALE (TX)       CLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKC...
HOCKLEY (TX)    CLEARFORKCLEAR FORKCLEARFORKCLEAR FORKCLEAR FO...
LAMB (TX)       CLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKCLEARFORKC...
Name: Reservoir, dtype: object
```

Comment: That solved the original issue, but I am assuming I coded this question wrong. The "Reservoir" column needs to be added for every county, meaning I need to count the number of "Reservoirs" for each county and plot it as a bar chart.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You mean number of unique Reservoirs for each county?

Comment: Yeah so for example in County: "Crosby", I want to count how many reservoir there are. I want it to look like Crosby (TX).....165 or whatever the amount of reservoirs are in that county.

Comment: Or use `count()`, im still not 100% sure what you need.

Comment: Say you have a blue bucket and in that bucket you have grapes, apples, and pears. I want the code to count only how many apples are in that blue bucket.

Comment: If every row represents a single Clearfork Well, use `count()`.
And you'll get the same result with `df['County/Parish'].value_counts()`